# list of months error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table defined as follows

```
create table test (
    m_year varchar2(10),
    val number
);
```

data looks like

```
myear   val
Jan 10  876
Sep 10  709
Jan 11  46
Apr 11  99
Jan 12  878
```

I want to get output as

```
01-Jan-10 876
01-Feb-10 876
'
'
'
01-Sep-10 709
'
'
'
sysdate 878
```

My query looks like

```
select to_char(add_months(myear,level-1)) months,val
from (
    select val, to_date(myear,'mm-yyyy') myear,
           lead(to_date(myear,'mm-yyyy'),1,sysdate) over (order by to_date(myear,'mm-yyyy')) as nxt
    from test
)
connect by level <= months_between(nxt,myear)+1;
```

Few months are being missed and I'm getting an infinite loop in the output

Comment: Format query and show all data in text form please

Comment: @Navyasri - create your test table with data or write a union and add this to the question.

Comment: Use `date` instead of `varchar2`.

Comment: Thanks for formatting the question @Schwern. It was my 1st question and I didn't understand how to use the editor. So I had some problem with formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (m_year varchar2(10),
  3     val    number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 'Jan 10', 876 from dual union
  3    select 'Sep 10', 709 from dual union
  4    select 'Jan 11', 46  from dual union
  5    select 'Apr 11', 99  from dual union
  6    select 'Jan 12', 878 from dual;

5 rows created.
```

Query:

```
SQL> with
  2  dates as
  3    (select to_date(m_year, 'mon rr', 'nls_date_language = english') m_year,
  4            val
  5     from test
  6    ),
  7  whole_period as
  8    (select add_months(min_year, level - 1) m_year
  9     from (select min(m_year) min_year,
 10                 trunc(sysdate, 'mm') max_year
 11           from dates
 12          )
 13     connect by level <= months_between(max_year, min_year) + 1
 14    )
 15  select
 16    w.m_year,
 17    last_value(d.val) ignore nulls over
 18      (order by w.m_year rows between unbounded preceding and current row) val
 19  from whole_period w left join dates d on d.m_year = w.m_year
 20  order by w.m_year;

M_YEAR            VAL
---------- ----------
01.01.2010        876
01.02.2010        876
01.03.2010        876
01.04.2010        876
01.05.2010        876
01.06.2010        876
01.07.2010        876
01.08.2010        876
01.09.2010        709
01.10.2010        709
01.11.2010        709
01.12.2010        709
01.01.2011         46
01.02.2011         46
01.03.2011         46
01.04.2011         99
01.05.2011         99
01.06.2011         99
01.07.2011         99
01.08.2011         99
01.09.2011         99
01.10.2011         99
01.11.2011         99
01.12.2011         99
01.01.2012        878
01.02.2012        878
01.03.2012        878
<snip>
01.03.2018        878
01.04.2018        878
01.05.2018        878

101 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks for the query! It works perfectly. Let me know the problem with the query I wrote, if possible. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The lazy way of doing the same - easy to read, easy to maintain. The distinct may slow down the performance. 
And next time please add your test data and structures to your posts. You will get answers faster.

```
SELECT DISTINCT add_months(start_date, LEVEL-1) final_date
     , start_date
     , end_month
  FROM
(
SELECT to_date(myear) start_date 
     , LAG(to_date(myear)) OVER (ORDER BY myear DESC) end_date
     , MIN(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM myear)) OVER (ORDER BY myear) start_month
     , MAX(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM myear)) OVER (ORDER BY myear DESC) end_month
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM myear) 
                              ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM myear))  rno
  FROM
(
SELECT to_date('01-2010', 'mm-yyyy') myear FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('09-2010', 'mm-yyyy') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('01-2011', 'mm-yyyy') FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT to_date('04-2011', 'mm-yyyy') FROM dual
)
)
WHERE rno = 1
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_month
ORDER BY start_date
/

FINAL DATE  START DATE  END MONTH
----------------------------------
01-JAN-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-FEB-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-MAR-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-APR-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-MAY-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-JUN-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-JUL-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-AUG-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-SEP-10   01-JAN-10   9
01-JAN-11   01-JAN-11   4
01-FEB-11   01-JAN-11   4
01-MAR-11   01-JAN-11   4
01-APR-11   01-JAN-11   4
```